# How to change value on certain cells copied from another cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have these columns in Sheet 1 that I'll copy and paste into Sheet 2. I'll use filter on the level columns and copy only the visible cells. I wonder how to change column E values in Sheet 2.

| NIP | Name | Math Score | English Score | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Ariana | 67 | 67 | Senior High 1 |
| 1235 | Brian | 89 | 89 | Senior High 2 |
| 1236 | Charlie | 78 | 90 | Senior High 1 |
| 1237 | Harry | 85 | 86 | Senior High 3 |

The data above will be pasted into Sheet 2 and I wish to change the level column's value like this:

Senior High 1 and so on -> Level 1 and so on

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Filtering on the level column could mean that you want to create a sheet for each level. If that's true, you need to say so, consider if you really need the column anymore, how to name the sheets, etc. Please share more information.

Comment: No, I want to use filter so that only for example level 1 visible on sheet 1, and if I chose level 2 then only level 2 data is visible on sheet 1. 

Things I want to achieve are copy all the data visible on sheet 1 -> paste it into sheet 2 -> change the values of Column E in sheet 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy Filtered Data With Replace

[image]

Docs: [**Range.Replace**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace)

```vb
Sub CopyFilteredData()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    dws.UsedRange.Clear
    
    With dws.Range("A1")
        'srg.Rows(1).Copy
        '.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.Copy .Cells
        With .CurrentRegion
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 4) _
                .Replace "Senior High", "Level", xlPart, , False
            '.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Filtered data copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```